# Specifying random effects in R

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with repeated measurements among participants (subjects). Each subject is tied to a site (Iowa, Kansas, Tennessee, ....). A subject can only be in one site and does not appear in two different sites. *A participant is only in one state and cannot appear in two states at the same time.*

My goal is to:

a) Estimate random intercepts for both Site and subject.

b) Nest the subject under their respective sites.

So is this correct?

```
lme4::lmer(outcome ~ a1 + x1 + (1 | SiteID / SubjectID), data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample of your data to be certain, but your specification looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specification looks correct to me (see relevant code on p.7 of the [original paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v67/i01/) on `lme4`). It fits the relationship between the outcome and $x_1$ and $a_1$ while estimating random intercept variance of subjects within states (which includes the random intercept variance of states as well). This model pre-supposes that the residual term is normally distributed, else it may require using `glmer` instead.

The other important qualifier, which you already noted in your question, is that nobody appears in two different states, else you would fit a crossed random effects design that includes a random cluster term for each in `lme4`.

Comment: Thank you very much.